# Binding data to a Button in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have a repeater which has a hidden field of Parking_ID `<asp:HiddenField Value='<%# Eval("Parking_ID") %>' ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />` and a Button under it.

I tried binding the value to the button from the html, it is giving me an `error which indicates binding did not work.` The programming language for the form is C#

How can I bind the value of Parking_ID with its button in order to pass that value to another form? and how it can be passed to the other form?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not directly set the value to the button's `CommandArgument` property ?

For example...

`<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Parking_ID") %>' />`

And then in the code behind...

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Int32 value = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    Response.Redirect("URL?id=" + value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I am storing the value into a session and fetching the session into a label in the other form but still not getting the value.       `Dim value As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?id=" & value)
        Session("field4") = value`. This is on Default1.aspx. On Default2.aspx:      `Dim field4 As String = CType(Session.Item("field4"), String) label.text = field4` Any idea how can I successfully view it ? Regards